# There is a delay to refresh wifi networks when switching from an active connection

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9360.
After I select a WiFi network it connects successfully but I noticed when I try to switch to another network, the list only shows the one I'm currently connected to.

I thought this was a bug and I used to restart the network service. Then I decided to wait and I discovered that there is a delay. The list of networks gets refreshed 3-4 seconds after opening the dialog.

This did not occur on Ubuntu 17.10 which is the one I upgraded from.

Is this delay meant to be there?

[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: try the cli `nmcli d wifi list` it should output the wifi networks list with no delay. ... fyi, i have a from scratch ubu 18.04, the wifi networks list is always displayed with no delay except at the first run.